how to trigger a char in input ( @ like in mention someone) in angular
i have an input it should display a list on user to choose from and display it
it can be a text area or an input
i try to use this package Angular Mentions but it seems it's not supported in angular 15
angular version: 15
I have tried what suggested in comments : ngx-mentions
but got errors:


you can use this package instead https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-mentions
